# Django Tastypie returns multiple instances when filtering relationships

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I'm able to successfully query a one-to-many relationship by filter, but instead of just getting one single record with the matching objects, I get the same record repeated for every matching filtered object.

For example, if one restaurant has many inspections matching my filter, then Tastypie returns one instance of the restaurant with every matching score.

Is there any way to get a single record back even if it has multiple matching objects?

**Query**

```
http://test.com:8000/restaurants/api/restaurants/?format=json&onlinereports__insp_score__lte=35
```

**models.py**

```
class Restaurant(models.Model):
    rest_permit = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, verbose_name='Permit', db_index=True)
    rest_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='Name', db_index=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['rest_name']
        select_on_save = True


class OnlineReport(models.Model):
    insp_rest_permit = models.ForeignKey(Restaurant, null=False, to_field='rest_permit', related_name='onlinereports', db_index=True)
    insp_score = models.DecimalField(verbose_name='Score', decimal_places=2, max_digits=5, db_index=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['insp_date']
        select_on_save = True
```

**resources.py**

```
class OnlineReportResource(ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        queryset = OnlineReport.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'onlinereports'
        filtering = {
            'insp_score': ALL,
        }

class RestaurantResource(ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        queryset = Restaurant.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'restaurants'
        filtering = {
            'onlinereports': ALL_WITH_RELATIONS,
        }

    onlinereports = fields.ToManyField(
        OnlineReportResource,
        'onlinereports',
        null=True,
        full=True
    )
```

**Example return:**

```
{
limit: 20,
next: null,
offset: 0,
previous: null,
total_count: 2
},
objects: [
    {
    onlinereports: [
        {
            id: 2526,
            insp_score: "11.00"
        },
        {
            id: 47882,
            insp_score: "-7.00"
        },
        {
            id: 47880,
            insp_score: "94.00"
        }
    ],
    rest_name: "Restaurant A",
    rest_permit: 2037
    },
    {
    onlinereports: [
        {
            id: 2526,
            insp_score: "11.00"
        },
        {
            id: 47882,
            insp_score: "-7.00"
        },
        {
            id: 47880,
            insp_score: "94.00"
        }
    ],
    rest_name: "Restaurant A",
    rest_permit: 2037
    }
]
```

**Desired return:**

```
{
limit: 20,
next: null,
offset: 0,
previous: null,
total_count: 1
},
objects: [
    {
    onlinereports: [
        {
            id: 2526,
            insp_score: "11.00"
        },
        {
            id: 47882,
            insp_score: "-7.00"
        },
        {
            id: 47880,
            insp_score: "94.00"
        }
    ],
    rest_name: "Restaurant A",
    rest_permit: 2037
    }
]
```

**SOLUTION**
Adding .distinct() to the RestaurantResource() queryset worked:

```
class RestaurantResource(ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        queryset = Restaurant.objects.all().distinct()
        resource_name = 'restaurants'
        filtering = {
            'onlinereports': ALL_WITH_RELATIONS,
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `distinct()` for your queryset. This eliminates duplicate rows from the query results.

```
queryset = OnlineReport.objects.all().distinct()
```

Comment: Thanks, adding .distinct() to the RestaurantResource queryset worked. I had tried this before but it didn't seem to work; I tried again after manually restarting the server and it worked.